# htaccess set multiple cookie in one rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I need to set two cookie in one htaccess rewrite rule as I want to redirect using two values of cookie.

I am trying this way but it sets onlly one cookie

```
 //conditions..
 RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,CO=cookie1:yes:.example.com,CO=cookie2:yes:.example.com]
```

Please suggest a way to set two cookie in one rewrite rule.

Thanks.

Comment: cookies works with  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ... [NC]`

Comment: @diEcho This is the way to check cookie if I know correctly, I need to set two cookie instead verify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you set multiple cookies:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*cookie1=yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=cookie1:yes:.example.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*cookie2=yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,CO=cookie2:yes:.example.com]
```

1. First rule does nothing but set a cookie names `cookie1`.
2. Second sets a cookie names `cookie2` and does a redirect to itself.